# Is it possible to directly save crystal report to pdf format without installing crystal report in client pc from C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, crystal-reports, pdf-generation

I had developed windows form application year ago, which calculates certain stuff and displays report in Printable text format in crystal reports. I had written certain static text in crystal report and displays report in crystal report.
Now there is certain changes in requirement. I need to display the same report in pdf format but without installing crystal report in client pc, because every pc doesn't have crystal report viewer installed, so my company want to directly export to pdf, without installing crystal report.

My report contains, Company Logo, Some forms texts, and the dynamic data which are calculated from windows form application,

Comment: if you have done the report in CR itself, then I doubt that you would be able to achieve this since even if you are to export directly to PDF it would request for the CR runtime etc. In such a scenario, I would of course use MS Report as it is bundled with Visual Studio.

Comment: If you have a Crystal Report, you need to have at least the **runtime** of CR installed on the computer to render the report - into whatever output format you want. You cannot render a CR report *without* any trace of CR on your machine...

Comment: So,, it is impossible to convert crystal report to pdf without installing crystal report runtime in client pc???

Comment: Yes, it's impossible - if you **have** a Crystal Report in your application, there **must be** at least the CR runtime on that computer using the app

Comment: It means,, its not possible to convert into Word, Excel any format without installing CR runtime on the pc using the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web service, wcf or web api that can create the report on the server where you have Crystal Reports installed and export it to pdf, all you need to do is to call that service and it should return a byte array that you will populate by reading the pdf file with:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(path)
```

Comment: I am talking about windows form application, and offline use.

Comment: Then that is not possible. But as long as I'm concerned, you can install it on your clients pc for free: http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/implement/licensing.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe. While you do not need to install the full blown Crystal Report desktop client, you do need a run-time from SAP to be involved so an .RPT file can be the input file to generate yoru PDF output file.

The executable and the required drivers are here:

https://github.com/rainforestnet/CrystalReportsNinja/tree/032aef5508a524deaad8c53f923bc6dc925f7085/Deployment

https://github.com/rainforestnet/CrystalReportsNinja

- CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20.zip (runtime needed for 32-bit Windows machine)
- CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20.zip (runtime needed for 64-bit Windows machine)
- CrystalReportsNinja.exe (Executable compiled by Visual Studio 2017 for .NET Framework 4.5). This is part of the github repo.